# iOS app won’t show feed before ~1 month in the past.

Tags: bug, ios-app

When I scroll to the bottom of my feed, I get a “Request Failed” notification. As of posting this report, the feed stops June 8, 2016.

- App Version: 1.5.1.2
- Device: iPhone 5c (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.1 (Build 13E238)